# Link two sheets in excel - So a row added in one gets added in the second

Tags: excel

I'd like to know if it is possible to link two sheets so that if I add a row in one sheet it autmatically gets added to the second sheet.

Thanks.

Comment: Add a blank row, or a row of data?  At the end of the existing data, or in the middle? Generally, yes, you can use the worksheet_change event to do this.  Have you tried anything?

Comment: Honestly this is a question I got asked by someone, but you are right. It isn't very clear. let me clarify and update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly -- I'm pretty sure you can't link an entire sheet.  But you could use formulas with cell references, e.g. `=Sheet2!B2` refers to cell B2 from Sheet2.

You could also try the `vlookup()` formula function.  If you have a table defined somewhere in the workbook, you can use this function to return the value from one column of the table based on the supplied value from another column in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can "Group" sheets together by holding down CTRL and selecting the tabs of the sheets to be grouped. Adding and deleting rows and columns would result in the same treatment over all the selected sheets. But this is temporary and is lost as soon as another sheet is selected or the file is closed.

For a longer term entanglement, you would need VBA code.